# What is the origin of "oui" in French?

Tags: étymologie, linguistique

Other Latin languages (that I am aware of at least) use "si". I know that there is a "si" also in French that is used to answer questions posed in a negative way, but it surprises me the usage of the word "oui" in the other more predominant cases. So, what are the roots of the word "oui"?

Comment: At least another Latin language doesn't use *si*. In Corsican, yes is 'ie' /j'e/ which comes from Latin *ille est*, Tuscan *Gli è* = "That is".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found what you are looking for [here](http://www.dicocitations.com/definition_littre/23306/Oui.php):

> La forme primitive est oïl, toujours dissyllabe, et formée du latin
>   hoc illud, oui cela (hoc ayant pris le sens de oui : Ne dit ne o ne
>   non, R. de Cambrai 264) ; oïl est donc fait comme nennil, qui
>   représente non illud, non cela. Picard, awi ; Berry, voui ; wallon,
>   awoi, dans lequel Grandgagnage regarde l'a comme prosthétique ;
>   bourguig. vouei ; différents dialectes cités par Grandgagnage ai, âï,
>   oï. On trouve dans les anciens textes, quoique rarement, des formes
>   singulières de ce mot : oal, ouail, ol, odil.

**Meaning:**

The original form (of *oui*) is `oïl`, and which is compoused of the latin words `hoc illud` meaning *oui cela* (*hoc* became *oui*).

*oïl* is   made like the word *nennil*  which represents `non illud` meaning *non cela*.

It is spoken as:

- [Picard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard_language): `awi`
- [Berry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berry_%28province%29), `voui`
- [Wallon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Walloon_language): `awoi`
- [Bourguig](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burgundian_language_%28O%C3%AFl%29): `vouei`

Different dialects mentioned by [Grandgagnage](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_Grandgagnage):  `ai`, `âï`, `oï`.

We can also rarely find in ancient texts very typical forms of *oui*: `oal`, `ouail`, `ol`, `odil`

Comment: I can translate you what I quoted, if you ask me.

Comment: that would be great

Comment: Une note pour votre information. L'extrait présenté provient directement de la section étymologie du [_Littré_](http://www.littre.org/definition/oui) que _Dicocitations_ copie. Merci.

Answer (score 4):

To expand a little ...

First, there was no word for "yes" in Latin. If you wanted to express an affirmation you had to say something explicit, although perhaps terse. E.g. "etiam" ("indeed" or "as always"), "ita est" ("that's it"), "sic est" ("it is thus"), "est" ("it is"), "hoc illic" ("this is it"), etc.

During the Middle Ages the Latin/Romance dialects developed explicit words for "yes" (presumably because other languages that influenced them like Gothic had such a concept). But since there was no single word in Latin they  went in different directions, hence the different words. In parts of Spain and Italy the expression "sic est", abbreviated to "sic", became "sí" (and "sim"). In southern France, "hoc illic", abbreviated to "hoc", became "oc". In northern France, "hoc illic" morphed into "oc il'", "oil", and finally "oui"; but they also picked up the "si" thing as well. In Romania, they picked up "da", obviously from Slavic. Sardinian has "eja"; I don't know where that comes from.

---

Ref: https://books.google.com/books?id=lKERAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA186

Answer (score 1):

The word « si » does exist in French still and is used to contradict negative assertions.

- Vous n'êtes pas d'ici!
- Si, je suis né ici.

Comment: Did you read this part of the question: "I know that there is a "si" also in French that is used to answer questions posed in a negative way" ?

Comment: Oops! I guess not.  I like the word so much I just had to write about it without rereading your question.  My bad.